# RSA - Archer - Hide multiple fields in a search result

Tags: archer

When performing a search in Archer, the result contains some un-necessary fields. Is there a way to show only fields that belong  to Application "General information" ? In other words, there are some fields that are suggested to being added to "General Information" tab which appear in a search result.

I know I can disable these fields by selecting the field, then clicking on "modify field properties", "options" and untick the show field in a search result.

Since I have multiple applications and a lot of fields, doing this will take a lot of time. Is there any script or trick to hide all these fields in a search result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use the API and create your own search XML to contain only the fields you want to see.

But short of doing that, I think you've hit the nail on the head. You'll need to go into each application and then modify each of the fields you don't want shown. I don't think it's a waste of time, as you're surely not changing this search result every time... it's a one time deal and if it makes it easier for you or the end users, it's certainly worth it IMO.

Comment: Well you are right. This is a painful solution but since it has to performed once I assume this is the "right" one

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the database then you can modify table "fielddef" and make fields not searchable by default. You can join "fielddef" table with "level" and "moduletranslation" and target only specific modules this way.

I don't have the SQL code for this since I didn't have to make a bulk update to the fields and make them not searchable.

It should take 5 min to join these 3 tables and make an update if you are good with SQL.